# Meaning of 'others' and 'group' in Unix system file

Tags: unix, ssh, chmod, chown

I wanna know what's the real meaning of 'others' in Unix System File.

Okay I understand stuff like 755, and tips for remember things like 5 refers to Read Permission(4) + Execute Permission(1) etc...

But what does 'others' and 'group' really mean please ? Is it about for example a person who connect through SSH ?

If I use tools like Yeoman(yo), or NPM, did 'others' refers to theses tools that often create folders and files OR their actions depends of my permissions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Unix `Users` belong to `Groups`. So a permission for a Group means: for all the other users of the group(s) to which the user belong to, while Others means a permission for all the other users (that is users different from the current user and not belonging to one of its groups).

Comment: Thank you for this explicit and conscise answer. If i'm the user johndoe and another johndoe connects through ssh can he benefits of my privileges ?

Comment: Johndoe is always the same user. A user can make multiple connections, through SSH or telnet or other tools. For each (possibly different) connections, it has always the same rights, since it is always the "same" user. So, the answer is yes.

Comment: You are wellcome. Remember to thick the answer with "accepted" (the green tick), but only if you are satisfied of it, thanks!